# Is there a standard option to discard NON-whitespace characters from std::istream until whitespace is encountered?

Tags: c++

I'm pretty sure the answer to this is going to be `No`, but I'm asking anyway.

The standard `std::ws` I/O manipulator discards whitespace from a `std::istream` until a non-whitespace character is encountered.

But, is there a standard *efficient* option to do the opposite - discard non-whitespace characters until whitespace is encountered?

I know that `std::istream::ignore()` can be used, but that requires specifying a max count and/or a delimiter. But, what if you don't know what the next whitespace character is going to be?  It might be `' '` or `'\t'` or `'\n'`. The count can be `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` to read until EOF, but there is no option to specify multiple delimiters, or to use a comparison predicate.

The only viable option I can think of is to use the `>>` extraction operator to read into a temporary `std::string`, eg:

```cpp
int value;
if (!(cin >> value))
{
    cin.clear();

    string ignored;
    cin >> ignored;
}
```

But that has the potential to allocate memory for data that is just going to be discarded right away.

I was hoping for something more like a `nonws` I/O manipulator, or an `>>` overload for `std::ignore`, or something like that, eg:

```cpp
int value;
if (!(cin >> value))
{
    cin.clear();

    cin >> nonws;
    or:
    cin >> std::ignore;
    or:
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),
        [](unsigned char c){ return !iswspace(c); }
    );
}
```

Obviously, those don't exist, but is there any other option like that to discard non-whitespace characters from a `std::istream`, without allocating dynamic memory, using a max-sized `char[]` buffer, or running a manual loop on `istream::(peek|get)`?  Basically, doing everything that `istream::ignore()` already does, but using an `iswspace()`-like check for the delimiter?

I'm primarily thinking of this for situations where the `>>` operator fails an extraction, ie of a numeric value, and the current input should be discarded, but ONLY for the *current word*, NOT all the way to the next line break.

---

Bonus: Has anything like this ever been proposed for inclusion in the C++ standard?

Comment: possibly it's easier to read and discard the non-whitespace.

Comment: What about `imbue`-ing stream with locale that alters ctype with inverted whitespace/non-whitespace identity?

Comment: @Jasen that is basically what I'm asking for, but an *efficient* read, and preferably a read that is handled by the standard library rather than in my own code.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I thought of it, but extracting locale, replacing character classification, imbue-ing, performing operation and reimbue-ing  stream again looks like opposite of efficient. It is probably better to write your own manipulator.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie now, that is an interesting idea! Would that then allow `std::ws` to act as `std::discardNonWs` instead? I'll have to play around with that

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, it would (I often use it to add punctuation to the list of "whitespace" characters), but it will affect  *all* formatted operations. You will have to restore locale back if you want to perform formatted extractions again.

Comment: Would appear we have a fox-guarding-the-hen-house type question here. Learning is bound to occur.

Comment: Would there be any advantage to manipulating the `std::streambuf` get-area either directly or in combination with a `std::stringstream` to make the get-area available as a single `std::string` or raw buffer that may allow something like a `std::find` or `find_first_not_of` to scan the get area to identify the next available whitespace, discarding anything up to that point? (this is a thought, I've not tried to write it out yet)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the problem with using a `std::streambuf` is that the existing `>>` operator that reads into a `streambuf` will read until EOF is reached, which is not what I'm asking for, and I don't see an option to change that behavior.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Can't you just read into a string and then throw it away?

Comment: @NicolBolas yes, I could (see the update to my question), but I'd rather not, if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I doubt there is such option, at least I do not know about it. However, it is easy to write manipulator doing something like that yourself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>

std::istream& nows(std::istream& in)
{
    const auto& ctype = std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(in.getloc());

    if (not in) return in;

    for (std::istream::int_type c = in.peek(); c != std::istream::traits_type::eof(); c = in.peek()) {
        if ( ctype.is(std::ctype_base::space, std::istream::traits_type::to_char_type(c)) )  
            break;
        in.get();
    }
    return in;
}

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> nows;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    std::cout << input << '\n';
    std::cout << "----|----|" << std::endl;
}
```

Templating this code to work with all instances of `basic_istream` is left as excercise for the reader.

After feeding line `123     4567 8` as input we get

```
     4567 8
----|----|
```

as output. As you can see, `nows` manipulator consumed all non-whitespace characters until it encountered first whitespace.

Comment: I decided to check `std::ws` implementation: after all, this manipulator is the same thing with one comparison inverted; and found out that my code is pretty close to MSVC implementation. https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/istream#L906